# can we make applications using visual studio professional or express edition?

Tags: visual-studio

sorry for such silly question, I'm fresher i want to know, can we make applications using visual studio professional or express edition?, and what is the difference between them? thanks for your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. Visual Studio Professional and Express Edition are IDE's that can program in C++, F#, C#, and VB.NET. Both versions have the same compiler but the Professional has more templates.

In conclusion for general development they are  both the same.

Comment: but i heard sometimes express edition doesn't support "Adds-on" ..what si the difference between them?

Comment: those "adds-on" are the templates.